# JQuery - Modify the attributes of a subset of a class

Tags: jquery

supposing I have to modify the attributes of a subset of a class (same class name), for example, only those that have an indefinite href. 
I tried this

```
if(jQuery('.aaa').attr('href') === "undefined")
{ 
   jQuery(this).css( "cursor", "default" );  
   jQuery(this).removeAttr('href');
}
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work

```
jQuery( ".aaa" ).filter(function( index ) {
    return jQuery( ".aaa", this ).attr('href') === "undefined";
  }).css( "cursor", "default" );
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: All you need to do is master [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and possibly the [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/?s=.filter) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the only way for href to be `undefined` is for the attribute to be absent.   If you're looking for empty or bare href attributes, test for the empty string instead:

```js
// classnames so you can see what matches what
$('.aaa:not([href])').addClass('undefined');
$('.aaa[href=""]').addClass('empty');
```

```css
.undefined{background-color:red}
.empty {background-color:blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="aaa">No href</a>
<a class="aaa" href="">Empty href</a>
<a class="aaa" href="#">Non-empty href</a>
<a class="aaa" href>Bare href</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to modify the css of anchor whose `href` is `undefined`

```
jQuery(".aaa").filter(function(index) {
    //return jQuery(this).attr('href') === "undefined";
    return this.href === undefined;
}).css("cursor", "default");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I see, inspecting the page: `<a class="aaa" href="">TEXT</a>`